# Apple Yosemite error installing openAFS from source

Tags: macos, installation, package, osx-yosemite, openafs

I recently tried to install openAFS from source on a mac with OS Yosemite. 
I have almost completed it. However once I have created the dmg file and opened it to run the pkg file inside, I get the error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.installer.pagecontroller error -1.) . How do you fix this?

Thanks for the help.

Alex

P.s
Past question related to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959675/afs-and-yosemite-on-mac

Comment: I can't answer this one (I don't have a system to test with), but I just wanted to mention: if you can't find an answer here, try asking on the port-darwin@openafs.org mailing list (list info is [here](http://lists.openafs.org/mailman/listinfo/port-darwin))